# How can I correctly align the database source between php artisan tinker and serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am new to laravel and I'm going through the laracast tutorials and all is well except that I have to constantly toggle my database source within my `.env` file via the `DB_DATABASE=` option.

- When I use `php artisan serve`, my database connection must be set to `DB_DATABASE=../database/database.sqlite`. Failure to do so results in the php error message: `InvalidArgumentException: Database (database/database.sqlite) does not exist.`
- When I want to use `php artisan tinker`, I have to change it to `DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite`. Failure to do so results in the Command line error: `InvalidArgumentException with message 'Database (../database/database.sqlite) does not exist.'`

**How can I correct this so that I do not have to constantly switch back and forth?**

Comment: Have you tried using a full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify it directly in `config/database.php` instead of in `.env`:

```
'database' => database_path('database.sqlite')
```

If this doesn't work, you can also opt for this:

```
'database' => empty(request()->server->get('HTTP_HOST')) ? 'database/database.sqlite' : '../database/database.sqlite'
```

What happens here is that in php cli `HTTP_HOST` is not available, so if it's empty then it means you are using tinker and not php's built-in server.